# Base ClearCase: Diff Between */... and

Tags: clearcase

I am using base ClearCase and have a config spec question. Please consider these two rules (only one of which I would put in my config spec):

## 1

```
element /cl5_sw_ste/DCT/*/... /main/0 -mkbranch rel_drop5
```

## 2

```
element /cl5_sw_ste/DCT/... /main/0 -mkbranch rel_drop5
```

What is the difference between them?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From [`config spec` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm))

A selection rule is formed as `scope / pattern / version-selector`.
The difference is in the **pattern**:

```
element /cl5_sw_ste/DCT/*/... /main/0 -mkbranch rel_drop5
```

Means the selection rule will apply to all directories under `DCT`.

You could rewrite it as:

```
element /cl5_sw_ste/DCT/* /main/0 -mkbranch rel_drop5
```

(you don't need the final `/...`, but in both case, DCT itself is not concerned by the version selector `/main/0 -mkbranch rel_drop5`: that is bad, since any element you add or remove directly under `DCT` would make a new version for `DCT` itself, and it won't be in `rel_drop5`)

```
element /cl5_sw_ste/DCT/... /main/0 -mkbranch rel_drop5
```

Means the selection rules will apply to `DCT` *and* all the directories under `DCT`.
That is usually what you see when working with branches.